# I wrote a function to break a string into parts delimitted by $ Now I need to access it with select from but getting error

Tags: string, oracle, variables, dynamic, split

I have created following function to split a given string delimited by `$`.

I want to call the function as part of SQL query and get the result as rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_tokenize2
  ( p_string IN CLOB
    -- p_delim in varchar2
  ) 
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
AS
   cur1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur1 FOR
      SELECT regexp_substr(p_string
                          ,'[^$]+'
                          ,1
                          ,LEVEL) AS str
      FROM   sys.dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(p_string
                                      ,'\$') + 1;
   RETURN cur1;
END string_tokenize2;
/
```

However when I tried it using in a SQL resulted in following error.

Kindly assist me how to proceed here ,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select string_tokenize2('')from dual;

put your IN variable in the ( )

Comment: I did .. please see the image I attached.

Comment: also I want the result in table format .. doing select string_tokeize2('asd$asd$') from dual 
giving me a row like as<>asd<> (array type)

Comment: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/PL-SQL/collection-types/return-table-from-function/index

Answer (score 0):

You can either

**1) use xmltable and xmltype to read data from sys_refcursor functions results if you need that data in `select` statement:**
ie you can use the same your function without any changes, but read it using xmltable+xmltype:

```sql
select * 
from xmltable(
        '/ROWSET/ROW'
        passing xmltype(string_tokenize2('1$2$3$4'))
        columns
          str varchar2(100) path 'STR'
        );
```

Results:

```
STR
---------------------------------------
1
2
3
4
```

**2) or use plsql implicit results** if you are just need to get data from any client: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1

Example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE string_tokenize2
  ( p_string IN CLOB
    -- p_delim in varchar2
  ) 
AS
   cur1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur1 FOR
      SELECT regexp_substr(p_string
                          ,'[^$]+'
                          ,1
                          ,LEVEL) AS str
      FROM   sys.dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(p_string
                                      ,'\$') + 1;
   DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur1);
END string_tokenize2;
/
begin
   string_tokenize2('1,2,3,4');
end;
```

Result:

```
SQL> exec string_tokenize2('1,2,3,4');
ResultSet #1

STR
---------------------------------------
1,2,3,4
```

**3) or just return sys_refcursor to client app as a bind variable for fetching**:

```sql
begin
  :res := string_tokenize2('1,2,3,4');
end;
```

Example in sql*plus:

```sql
SQL> var res refcursor
SQL> exec :res := string_tokenize2('1$2$3$4');
SQL> print res

STR
--------------------
1
2
3
4
```

**4) Or varchar2 collections/varrays as suggested by other users**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any constraint to stick to the function as it is ? OR

Why not create an object type and change the function to return a table type and then use it in SQL ?

```
--create the type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_tokenize2_obj IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);

--Function changes
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_tokenize2(p_string IN CLOB) 
RETURN string_tokenize2_obj AS
   l_tab string_tokenize2_obj;
BEGIN
   SELECT to_char(str)
   BULK   COLLECT
   INTO   l_tab
   FROM   (SELECT regexp_substr(p_string
                               ,'[^$]+'
                               ,1
                               ,LEVEL) str
           FROM   dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(p_string
                                           ,'\$') + 1);
   RETURN l_tab;
END string_tokenize2;
/

SQL> SELECT column_value str FROM TABLE(string_tokenize2('abc$def$geh$ijkl'));

STR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc
def
geh
ijkl

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. this was what I was looking for  .. thanks !!!!! :)

Comment: Nice!!.would you mind accept/upvote the solution if it helped you. Cheers!!!